# .htaccess 301 redirect rule doesn't work because of capital letters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have some 301 redirect rules failing because of capital letters in the URL.  Problem is... that is how they appeared in the old site, so I would like them to be case-sensitive.

This doesn't work:

```
Redirect 301 /folder/HeyThere.html http://www.newsite.com
```

but this does

```
Redirect 301 /folder/heythere.html http://www.newsite.com
```

Doesn't seem like a lower-case character rule applies to both upper-case and lower-case letters, but I need to have this work for URLs with upper-case letters in them.  I'd like to have it work for both, but is there something I can do to ensure this works properly if someone comes from a URL with an upper-case character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use `mod_rewrite` for ignore case handling:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/heythere\.html$ http://www.newsite.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Due to presence of `NC` flag (no case) here it will redirect both `/folder/HeyThere.html` and `/folder/heythere.html` to newsite.

Comment: The syntax provided in your answer doesn't seem to be taking effect... for lower case or uppercase

Comment: Did you place `RewriteEngine On` before my rule? btw this should be placed in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` not inside `/folder/.htaccess`

Comment: Indeed.  I placed this rule after multiple after `Rewrite Engine On` and multiple working `301 Redirect` rules.  In the root.  Could there be another rule conflicting with this?

Comment: Make this rule your very first rule after `RewriteEngine On` and test in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Syntax looks like this `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/heythere\.html$ http://www.newsite.com [R=301,NC,L]` and it still doesn't work.  Old browser, new browser, cleared cached...

Comment: And what URL are you using to test this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47292/discussion-between-rcneil-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression with RedirectMatch for create dynamic rules.

RedirectMatch 301 /folder/(?i)HeyThere.html http://www.newsite.com

(?i) is used for case insensitivity for next characters.

I hope this will work for you :)